# Installing R-Studio

Tags: raspbian, software-installation

I am able to install R on my Pi using Raspbian Wheezy, and I'm trying to build R-Studio from source. Has anyone been successful getting R-Studio (Desktop or Server) installed on the Pi?

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing how you got on with this if there is an update. Is installing R pretty easy? What steps did you take?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: R is easy to install since its in the raspbian repository and the install process is the same for Debian. RStudio server would be nice to have a low cost web server to do work remotely and doesn't need to be very computationally powerful.