# Error while trying to compile RStudio

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, software-installation, make

I'm using Raspbian in a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

I've followed the guidelines in the RStudio Webpage and also in this topic https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=55828

```
sudo su
apt-get install git r-recommended
git clone https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio.git
cd rstudio
./dependencies/linux/install-dependencies-debian
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Server -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
make install
```

But when doing `cmake .. -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Server -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` it throws me this error:

```
CMake Error at src/cpp/session/CMakeLists.txt:23 (message):
  Dictionaries not found (re-run install-dependencies script to install)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I've tried reinstalling dependencies but that didn't help

This is the Error log:

```
Determining if the function getpeereid exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/pi/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTryCompileExec3944045131/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3944045131.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3944045131.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/pi/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3944045131.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=getpeereid   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3944045131.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CheckFunction$
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec3944045131
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3944045131.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=getpeereid    CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3944045131.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec3944045131 -rdynamic
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3944045131.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o: In function `main':
CheckFunctionExists.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `getpeereid'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3944045131.dir/build.make:88: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec3944045131' failed
make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec3944045131] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec3944045131/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec3944045131/fast] Error 2
```

Do you know what could be happening?

**EDIT 1:**

This is the output of running `./dependencies/linux/install-dependencies-debian`:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/rstudio# ./dependencies/linux/install-dependencies-debian
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
pkg-config is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
fakeroot is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
cmake is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
uuid-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libssl-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libbz2-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libpam0g-dev' instead of 'libpam-dev'
libpam0g-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libxslt1-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libapparmor1 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
apparmor-utils is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libboost-all-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libpango1.0-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-6-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  apt

E: Package 'openjdk-6-jdk' has no installation candidate
```

It tells me that openjdk-6-jdk is needed but it's not in the repos. I've installed openjdk-7-jdk manually, but installing it didn't work.

After doing that, I commented (#) the line in which tries to install openjdk-6-jdk. Now it follows installing packages and these are (the last lines) of the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ant is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
unzip is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
./dependencies/linux/install-dependencies-debian: line 58: cd: ../common: No such file or directory
```

I've entered again in the file `install-dependencies-linux` and these are the lines that fail:

```
cd ../common
./install-common
cd ../linux
```

But I don't know what's trying to install. After these lines, begin the lines of installing the Qt but that's for the RStudio Desktop version, not my Server version.

**EDIT 2:**

I discovered using the command `find / -name install-common` that there was a common directory under the dependencies directory. So I `cd`'ed to `/dependencies/common/` and manually performed a `./install-common`

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/rstudio/dependencies/common# ./install-common
--2015-11-21 19:26:41--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-buildtools/gin-1.5.zip
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 54.231.98.155
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|54.231.98.155|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1055663 (1.0M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘gin-1.5.zip’

gin-1.5.zip         100%[=====================>]   1.01M   951KB/s   in 1.1s

2015-11-21 19:26:43 (951 KB/s) - ‘gin-1.5.zip’ saved [1055663/1055663]

--2015-11-21 19:26:44--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-buildtools/gwt-2.7.0.zip
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 54.231.9.24
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|54.231.9.24|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 108818328 (104M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘gwt-2.7.0.zip’

gwt-2.7.0.zip       100%[=====================>] 103.78M  7.80MB/s   in 20s

2015-11-21 19:27:04 (5.27 MB/s) - ‘gwt-2.7.0.zip’ saved [108818328/108818328]

--2015-11-21 19:27:36--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-buildtools/junit-4.9b3.jar
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 54.231.49.132
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|54.231.49.132|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 247280 (241K) [application/java-archive]
Saving to: ‘junit-4.9b3.jar’

junit-4.9b3.jar     100%[=====================>] 241.48K   246KB/s   in 1.0s

2015-11-21 19:27:38 (246 KB/s) - ‘junit-4.9b3.jar’ saved [247280/247280]

--2015-11-21 19:27:38--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-buildtools/selenium-java-2.37.0.zip
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 54.231.112.67
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|54.231.112.67|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 24625928 (23M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘selenium-java-2.37.0.zip’

selenium-java-2.37. 100%[=====================>]  23.48M  2.28MB/s   in 16s

2015-11-21 19:27:55 (1.45 MB/s) - ‘selenium-java-2.37.0.zip’ saved [24625928/24625928]

--2015-11-21 19:28:00--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-buildtools/selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 54.231.114.92
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|54.231.114.92|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 34730734 (33M) [application/x-java-archive]
Saving to: ‘selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar’

selenium-server-sta 100%[=====================>]  33.12M  4.39MB/s   in 8.6s

2015-11-21 19:28:10 (3.84 MB/s) - ‘selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar’ saved [34730734/34730734]

--2015-11-21 19:28:10--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-buildtools/chromedriver-mac
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 54.231.96.144
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|54.231.96.144|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 22034760 (21M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘chromedriver-mac’

chromedriver-mac    100%[=====================>]  21.01M  5.39MB/s   in 4.8s

2015-11-21 19:28:15 (4.34 MB/s) - ‘chromedriver-mac’ saved [22034760/22034760]

--2015-11-21 19:28:15--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-buildtools/chromedriver-linux
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 54.231.97.227
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|54.231.97.227|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 19303552 (18M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘chromedriver-linux’

chromedriver-linux  100%[=====================>]  18.41M  2.53MB/s   in 9.4s

2015-11-21 19:28:25 (1.95 MB/s) - ‘chromedriver-linux’ saved [19303552/19303552]

--2015-11-21 19:28:25--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-buildtools/chromedriver-win.exe
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 54.231.13.152
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|54.231.13.152|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 6731776 (6.4M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘chromedriver-win.exe’

chromedriver-win.ex 100%[=====================>]   6.42M  2.52MB/s   in 2.6s

2015-11-21 19:28:29 (2.52 MB/s) - ‘chromedriver-win.exe’ saved [6731776/6731776]

--2015-11-21 19:28:29--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-dictionaries/core-dictionaries.zip
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 54.231.10.192
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|54.231.10.192|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 876339 (856K) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘core-dictionaries.zip’

core-dictionaries.z 100%[=====================>] 855.80K  1.00MB/s   in 0.8s

2015-11-21 19:28:31 (1.00 MB/s) - ‘core-dictionaries.zip’ saved [876339/876339]

--2015-11-21 19:28:31--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-buildtools/mathjax-23.zip
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 54.231.1.152
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|54.231.1.152|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1674748 (1.6M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘mathjax-23.zip’

mathjax-23.zip      100%[=====================>]   1.60M   578KB/s   in 2.8s

2015-11-21 19:28:35 (578 KB/s) - ‘mathjax-23.zip’ saved [1674748/1674748]

1.50.0 already installed in /opt/rstudio-tools/boost/boost_1_50_0
--2015-11-21 19:28:35--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-buildtools/pandoc-1.13.1.zip
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 54.231.64.184
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|54.231.64.184|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 115697042 (110M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘pandoc-1.13.1.zip’

pandoc-1.13.1.zip   100%[=====================>] 110.34M  1.99MB/s   in 44s

2015-11-21 19:29:20 (2.52 MB/s) - ‘pandoc-1.13.1.zip’ saved [115697042/115697042]

cp: cannot stat ‘pandoc-1.13.1/linux/debian/armv7l/pandoc*’: No such file or directory
```

And now when I perform again a cmake this is the output:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/rstudio/build# cmake .. -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Server -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-- Boost version: 1.50.0
-- Found R: /usr/lib/R
CMake Error at src/cpp/session/CMakeLists.txt:32 (message):
  rsconnect package not found (re-run install-dependencies script to install)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

At least now it throws an error in a different line!

**EDIT 3:**

I installed manually the dependencies inside the `install-common` and now the cmake command works! Yay!

Now I've performed a `make install` but it gets stuck here:

```
Buildfile: /home/pi/rstudio/src/gwt/build.xml

ext:
```

Comment: Old (dead) question on it [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14631/installing-r-studio)... What output did you get from the dependency installation (so `apt-get ...` and `./dependencies/linux/install-dependencies-debian`)?

Comment: @Wilf Thank you very much for your comment. I've edited the question,

Comment: @Wilf And sorry, the output from `apt-get ...` went all okay. `git is already the newest version.
r-recommended is already the newest version.`

Comment: Just a taxonomical point - for the record you either have a Raspberry Pi Model B+ or a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B - the second has three more processor cores (and twice the memory IIRC)...

Comment: Sorry, I wrote Raspberry Pi 2 Model B+ at the top of this post. I mean Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. Now it's correct, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using some tips from this thread (thank you!), another [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466363/unable-to-install-rstudio-server-on-raspberry-pi2/31594026#31594026), another [ARM install](https://github.com/jrowen/ARM-rstudio-server/blob/master/build_rstudio.sh) (on a Chromebook), and a lot of trial and error, I was able to get an RStudio Server v0.99.491 up and running on my Pi 2.

Sergio, what I think you're missing is:

1. Manually install pandoc.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y pandoc
   ```
2. A new GWT compiler. The process below will vary depending on how you have your directories setup. Basically, download the latest compiler, unzip it, and move it to the "compiler" folder.

   ```
   cd ~/downloads
   wget http://dl.google.com/closure-compiler/compiler-latest.zip
   unzip compiler-latest.zip
   rm COPYING README.md compiler-latest.zip
   sudo mv compiler.jar /home/pi/downloads/rstudio/src/gwt/tools/compiler/compiler.jar
   ```
3. Potentially, SWAP space. I've had mixed results getting it to compile with and without SWAP. What I do know is, I used SWAP to get the working install I have now.

For anyone else that may have had a hard time following the above process I did my best to compile it. NOTE: it will take HOURS to `./install-common` and `make install`. I think it took almost 4.5 hours to build `make install`.

```
sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install -y git r-recommended
cd /home/pi/downloads/
git clone https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio.git
cd /home/pi/downloads/rstudio/dependencies/common/
./install-common
cd /home/pi/downloads/rstudio/dependencies/linux/
./install-dependencies-debian

#saw java 6 was not installed. installed v7
apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk

#tried to make install, got an error about dictionaries not installed and rerun install-dependencies
cd /home/pi/downloads/rstudio/dependencies/common/
./install-common

#tried to make install, hangs at "ext:" so I tried manually installing pandoc, which should have been installed earlier, but apparently was not
apt-get install -y pandoc

#tried to make install, hangs at "ext:" so I tried installing the latest GWT compiler
cd ~/downloads
wget http://dl.google.com/closure-compiler/compiler-latest.zip
unzip compiler-latest.zip
rm COPYING README.md compiler-latest.zip
mv compiler.jar /home/pi/downloads/rstudio/src/gwt/tools/compiler/compiler.jar

#build and install works!
cd /home/pi/downloads/rstudio/
#remove build if exists
rm -r ./build
mkdir build
cmake -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Server -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
make install
```

I should add that there are a few more steps to getting the server up and running, but this is where I imagine most people were stuck. Here are the next steps taken from [jrowen's ARM build on a Chromebook](https://github.com/jrowen/ARM-rstudio-server/blob/master/build_rstudio.sh):

```
# Additional install steps
sudo useradd -r rstudio-server
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/rstudio-server/extras/init.d/debian/rstudio-server /etc/init.d/rstudio-server
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/rstudio-server 
sudo ln -f -s /usr/local/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rstudio-server /usr/sbin/rstudio-server
sudo chmod 777 -R /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/

# Setup locale
sudo apt-get install -y locales
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg-reconfigure locales
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
#echo 'export LANG=en_US.UTF-8' >> ~/.bashrc
#echo 'export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8' >> ~/.bashrc

# Clean the system of packages used for building
sudo apt-get autoremove -y cabal-install ghc openjdk-7-jdk pandoc libboost-all-dev
sudo rm -r -f ~/rstudio-$VERS
sudo apt-get autoremove -y

# Start the server
sudo rstudio-server start

# Go to localhost:8787
```

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange communities.  This seems like a decently written up answer to me!

Answer (score 1):

3 years later, based on dhewlett's answer, I was able to build RStudio 1.1.463 on Raspbian Stretch. I've put it all into a docker build for easier reproducibility. It comes in several parts.

First create a build environment for RStudio. The Dockerfile.build_env looks like this:

```
FROM balenalib/raspberrypi3-debian:stretch-build as build_env

ARG VERSION_MAJOR=1
ARG VERSION_MINOR=1
ARG VERSION_PATCH=463
ARG PACKAGE_RELEASE=1
ARG VERSION_TAG=${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH}

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y \
      galternatives \
      git \
      openjdk-8-jdk \
      pandoc \
      pandoc-citeproc \
      python-dev \
      r-recommended

RUN mkdir -p /home/pi/Downloads
WORKDIR /home/pi/Downloads

# Get the RStudio sources. We only download the version of the code we need,
# instead of HEAD. HEAD has dependencies that RaspberryPi3 Debian (v9 Stretch)
# currently doesn't satisfy, e.g. QT >= 5.10.
RUN set -x \
    && wget https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/archive/v${VERSION_TAG}.tar.gz -O rstudio.tgz \
    && tar xzf rstudio.tgz \
    && rm rstudio.tgz \
    && ln -s rstudio-${VERSION_TAG} rstudio

WORKDIR /home/pi/Downloads/rstudio/dependencies/linux
# We're going to use the system version of the boost library (version
# 1.62.0) instead of installing and building the RStudio version of boost
# (version 1.63.0) which takes several hours of build time.
RUN perl -i -pe 's/(^.*install-boost$)/# \1/s' ../common/install-common
RUN apt-get install libboost-all-dev
# Script installs qt-sdk only for x86 but we need armhf, so skip qt install.
RUN ./install-dependencies-debian --exclude-qt-sdk
# Extra dependencies to build rstudio-desktop: use the system QT libraries instead.
RUN apt-get install -y \
      libqt5opengl5-dev \
      libqt5sensors5-dev \
      libqt5svg5-dev \
      libqt5webkit5-dev \
      libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev \
      qt5-default \
      qt5-style-plugins \
      qtpositioning5-dev \
      qtwebengine5-dev

WORKDIR /home/pi/Downloads/rstudio
# Package building wants to grab QT library files to bundle them with the
# RStudio desktop .deb package. But bundling of system QT doesn't work due
# to path differences and is unnecessary anyway.
RUN sed -i -e 's#\(set(RSTUDIO_BUNDLE_QT\) TRUE#\1 FALSE#' src/cpp/desktop/CMakeLists.txt
# Add the package dependencies to system QT libraries.
RUN sed -i -e 's#\(^.*set(RSTUDIO_DEBIAN_DEPENDS "${RSTUDIO_DEBIAN_DEPENDS}libgstreamer0.10.*$\)#\1\nset(RSTUDIO_DEBIAN_DEPENDS "${RSTUDIO_DEBIAN_DEPENDS}libqt5webchannel5, libqt5webkit5, libqt5positioning5, libqt5sensors5, libqt5svg5, libqt5xml5, libqt5xmlpatterns5, ")#' package/linux/CMakeLists.txt
# Add our own package release (aka. Debian revision number) to the .deb file.
RUN sed -i -e 's#\(^.*\)-\(${PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE}\)#set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_RELEASE "'${PACKAGE_RELEASE}'")\n\1-${CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_RELEASE}_\2#' package/linux/CMakeLists.txt

# Constrain gwtc compiler to use a single worker - gwtc is a memory hog and
# running multiple workers is getting too tight with 1 GB RAM + 1 GB swap.
RUN perl -0777 -i -pe 's#(<arg value="-localWorkers"/>\s+<arg value=)"\d+"(/>)#\1"1"\2#s' src/gwt/build.xml

# Change "cmake_policy(SET CMP0020 OLD)" to "cmake_policy(SET CMP0043 OLD)"
# to avoid a build time complaint.
RUN sed -i -e s/CMP0020/CMP0043/g src/cpp/desktop/CMakeLists.txt

# We build in a separate directory.
RUN mkdir build
```

And build that image with:

```
docker build -t raspberrypi-rstudio-build-env -f Dockerfile.build_env .
```

Then build the RStudio Server Debian package with Dockerfile.server_deb:

```
# The compilation, especially gwtc (java), needs a lot of memory so you need
# to add more swap on your RP3 in order for the compile to succeed:
#   * In /etc/dphys-swapfile set CONF_SWAPSIZE=1024 (default is 100)
#   * Then run sudo service dphys-swapfile restart
#   * Once the build is done and you're happy with the result you can set
#     the swap space back to the default 100 MB with:
#     * In /etc/dphys-swapfile set CONF_SWAPSIZE=100
#     * sudo service dphys-swapfile restart

FROM raspberrypi-rstudio-build-env as build_env

ARG VERSION_MAJOR=1
ARG VERSION_MINOR=1
ARG VERSION_PATCH=463
ARG PACKAGE_RELEASE=1
ARG VERSION_TAG=${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH}
ARG BUILD_TAG=${VERSION_TAG}-${PACKAGE_RELEASE}

# Build only with parallelism 2 - gwtc is a memory hog. If you still run out
# of memory override this to 1.
ARG BUILD_PARALLELISM=2

WORKDIR /home/pi/Downloads/rstudio/build

RUN set -x \
    && cmake .. \
      -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Server \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
      -DRSTUDIO_PACKAGE_BUILD=1 \
      -DRSTUDIO_BOOST_VERSION=1.62.0 \
      -DRSTUDIO_USE_SYSTEM_BOOST=1 \
    && make preinstall -j${BUILD_PARALLELISM}
# Create the deb package. Unfortunately cpack wants to rerun the whole build,
# so we'll work around that by giving it an empty build rule.
# (There really should be a better way to avoid the rebuild.)
RUN set -x \
    && mv Makefile Makefile.orig \
    && echo 'preinstall:' > Makefile \
    && cpack -G DEB \
    && mv Makefile.orig Makefile
# The product of this build is: rstudio-server-${BUILD_TAG}_armhf.deb

# Extract only the finished Debian package and leave it in an empty docker
# image to reduce image size. If you want to capture the package in its
# build environment, build it only to stage --target=build_env
FROM scratch as package

# ARGs need to be redefined in every build stage to be accessible.
ARG VERSION_MAJOR=1
ARG VERSION_MINOR=1
ARG VERSION_PATCH=463
ARG PACKAGE_RELEASE=1
ARG VERSION_TAG=${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH}
ARG BUILD_TAG=${VERSION_TAG}-${PACKAGE_RELEASE}

COPY --from=build_env /home/pi/Downloads/rstudio/build/rstudio-server-${BUILD_TAG}_armhf.deb /
```

Build that image and extract the RStudio Server Debian package:

```
docker build -t raspberrypi-rstudio-server-deb -f Dockerfile.server_deb .
docker image save raspberrypi-rstudio-server-deb | tar xO --wildcards '*/layer.tar' | tar x
```

Similarly for the RStudio Desktop Debian Package you'll use Dockerfile.desktop_deb:

```
FROM raspberrypi-rstudio-build-env as build_env

ARG VERSION_MAJOR=1
ARG VERSION_MINOR=1
ARG VERSION_PATCH=463
ARG PACKAGE_RELEASE=1
ARG VERSION_TAG=${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH}
ARG BUILD_TAG=${VERSION_TAG}-${PACKAGE_RELEASE}

# Build only with parallelism 2 - gwtc is a memory hog. If you still run out
# of memory override this to 1.
ARG BUILD_PARALLELISM=2

WORKDIR /home/pi/Downloads/rstudio/build

RUN set -x \
    && cmake .. \
      -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Desktop \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
      -DRSTUDIO_PACKAGE_BUILD=1 \
      -DRSTUDIO_BOOST_VERSION=1.62.0 \
      -DRSTUDIO_USE_SYSTEM_BOOST=1 \
      -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/qmake \
    && make preinstall -j${BUILD_PARALLELISM}
# Create the deb package. Unfortunately cpack wants to rerun the whole build,
# so we'll work around that by giving it an empty build rule.
# (There really should be a better way to avoid the rebuild.)
RUN set -x \
    && mv Makefile Makefile.orig \
    && echo 'preinstall:' > Makefile \
    && cpack -G DEB \
    && mv Makefile.orig Makefile
# The product of this build is: rstudio--${BUILD_TAG}_armhf.deb

# Comment out next line for native build.
RUN [ "cross-build-end" ]

# Extract only the finished Debian package and leave it in an empty docker
# image to reduce image size. If you want to capture the package in its
# build environment, build it only to stage --target=build_env
FROM scratch as package

# ARGs need to be redefined in every build stage to be accessible.
ARG VERSION_MAJOR=1
ARG VERSION_MINOR=1
ARG VERSION_PATCH=463
ARG PACKAGE_RELEASE=1
ARG VERSION_TAG=${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH}
ARG BUILD_TAG=${VERSION_TAG}-${PACKAGE_RELEASE}

COPY --from=build_env /home/pi/Downloads/rstudio/build/rstudio--${BUILD_TAG}_armhf.deb /
```

Build that image and extract the RStudio Desktop Debian package:

```
docker build -t raspberrypi-rstudio-desktop-deb -f Dockerfile.desktop_deb .
docker image save raspberrypi-rstudio-desktop-deb | tar xO --wildcards '*/layer.tar' | tar x
```

Finally, install the .deb packages with apt which also pulls in the dependent packages. Make sure to update the package list first though:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install ./rstudio-server-1.1.463-1_armhf.deb
sudo apt install ./rstudio--1.1.463-1_armhf.deb
```