# Raspberry Pi RStudio

Tags: pi-2, make

I have used [link1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38407/error-while-trying-to-compile-rstudio?newreg=67323d9e94c94d13a80dc8b74d557e9a) and [link2](http://herb.h.kobe-u.ac.jp/raspiinfo/rstudio_en.html) and keep getting errors on *cmake .. -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Server -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release*.

**Error:**

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_LIBRARIES OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
/usr/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:380 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
src/cpp/core/CMakeLists.txt:204 (find_package)
```

**CMakeError.log:**

```
Determining if the function getpeereid exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/pi/Downloads/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_d7cd2/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_d7cd2.dir/build.make 
CMakeFiles/cmTC_d7cd2.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/Downloads/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_d7cd2.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=getpeereid   -o 
CMakeFiles/cmTC_d7cd2.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share$
Linking C executable cmTC_d7cd2
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_d7cd2.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=getpeereid    
CMakeFiles/cmTC_d7cd2.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_d7cd2 -rd$
CMakeFiles/cmTC_d7cd2.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o: In function `main':
CheckFunctionExists.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `getpeereid'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTC_d7cd2.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_d7cd2' failed
make[1]: *** [cmTC_d7cd2] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/rstudio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_d7cd2/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTC_d7cd2/fast] Error 2
```

Comment: And... what is the question?

Comment: Please don't expect that we follow two links to understand your problem. Please explain it.

Answer (score 0):

The second line of your error message tells you that you need OpenSSL If it's already installed then set the environment variables as mentioned in the error message. Otherwise you need to install OpenSSL

Comment: Thank you. OpenSSL is already installed (I forgot to mention that I had already checked). I had forgotten to Google the error. I will try for now what I found at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248775/cmake-not-able-to-find-openssl).

Comment: I tried what I could understand (the basic install suggestions), but I am confused on the context of the environment variables. What files and I supposed to edit?