# Installing RStudio on a Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu

I am planning to do a classroom project using R and RStudio IDE. I am able to run R from command line. I installed the package using the command below `sudo apt-get install r-base`

Now I am trying to install the RStudio IDE and I found this [Installing RStudio](http://herb.h.kobe-u.ac.jp/raspiinfo/rstudio_en.html) link which has a lot of packages and dependencies to be installed.

I have also checked the RStudio source code on GitHub and the [GitHub Instructions](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/INSTALL) are different there, will those instructions are applicable to the armhf-based Raspberry Pi Ubuntu MATE.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, instructions for *compiling* don't change from architecture to architecture very much. Compiling code for x86 and compiling for armhf will usually just need the same commands, so  I would expect the [official README](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/INSTALL) to be accurate.

The other page you linked to says that is adapted from [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/42102/58316), which is in fact from our own little corner of the Internet, *Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange*.

It's much more obvious why the other link does all of these unusual steps if you view it in the context of the Stack Exchange Q&A – someone tried following the official instructions on the Pi, and it didn't work for them, but another user was able to find some steps to make it work.

I suggest you **try the official instructions first**, and if you have trouble with those, [this answer's steps](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/42102/58316) might be worth trying. There might be slight variations given that you're using Ubuntu MATE, but the only way to find out is by trying. Good luck!